# JTable + getColumnClass() returns null if a cell contains NULL

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to sort my JTable by extending DefaultTableModel and overrriding  getColumnClass() as follows:

```
 public Class getColumnClass(int c) {     

  return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}
```

It works perfectly fine if there is no NULL in that table cell.
So I modified it in following way:

```
  public Class getColumnClass(int c) {


  for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.size(); rowIndex++){

    Object[] row = data.get(rowIndex);

    if (row[c] != null) {
        return getValueAt(rowIndex, c).getClass();
    }
  }
  return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
 }
```

Now, again, it works fine if there is atleast one cell in the column which is not NULL.
But if all of the cells in the column is NULL, it doesn't work ('casue it returns nullPointerException).

Please ............help....
thanks in advance

Hasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick 'default' type. return String.class; is quite safe solution.

Comment: no, it's not "safer" than any other arbitrary type (other than Object)

Comment: If I do so, then it won't sort Integer properly.

Comment: public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
   
   
   for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.size(); rowIndex++){
    
  Object[] row = data.get(rowIndex);
    
  if (row[c] != null) {
   return getValueAt(rowIndex, c).getClass();
  }
   }
      return String.class;
  }

Fixed the problem by returning **String.class** if all cells in the column is NULL.

Comment: Ye, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 6):

Do you know what type you expect each column to contain before hand?

If so then you can build an array with the class objects and just return the appropriate one.

```
Class[] columns = new Class[]{String.class, String.class, Date.class};

public Class getColumnClass(int c) {  
     return columns[c];
}
```

Comment: well then your only option is to do what the other answers suggested and pick something to return when the value is null.

Answer (score 3):

This is the general code I use:

```
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
    {
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };
```

Comment: hopefully not in production code <g> - typically, it's a bad thing to no know the type: without that knowledge, you can't safely guarantee that _all_ cells in that column have the type of the first

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely simple to solve this problem. Look at the code changes i made. This code was tested and is error free

```
public Class getColumnClass(int c) {  
  int columnCount;
  // dataModel is an object of the data Model class(default or abstract)
  columnCount=dataModel.getRowCount();
    if(columnCount<=1){
       return String.class;
    }
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}
```

Comment: ehh .. no, that's not a solution (even if you don't confuse readers by naming the _rowCount_ as _columnCount_ :-) And it's wrong to pick an arbitrary type (other than Object), as I already commented in some of the other answers. Also, the condition <= 1 would return that arbitrary type if there are exactly one row. And still you don't guard against a _null_ value

Answer (score -1):

```
public Class getColumnClass(int c) 
    {     
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.size(); rowIndex++)
    {
        Object[] row = data.get(rowIndex);
        if (row[c] != null) {
            return getValueAt(rowIndex, c).getClass();
        }   
    }
    return String.class;
}
```

Fixed the problem by return **String.class** if all cells in the column is NULL

Comment: that's _wrong_ (as alredy mentioned in my comment to the answer you accepted)